# Reset tab when I press another tab

Tags: iphone, xcode, navigation, uitabbarcontroller, reset

I'm working on an iPhone app build from a TabBarController in the Storyboard. Most of the tabs lead to NavigationControllers with TableViews. Now when I press another tab, I want the tab I just left to jump back to main/default view. I want this to happen with some of the tabs, but with some of them it's more practical if it remains in the view it was left. How can I implement this to my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reset a view controller back to its original state, you can do this in viewWillAppear of a the given ViewController.